# Paging is not working fine using extjs grid and Java rest services

Tags: extjs

I have one extjs grid panel. it contains Paging toolbar on it.

Here is Paging Toolbar Code:

```
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: 'courseStoreForGrid',   // same store GridPanel is using
            pageSize: 2,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
```

Here is my Store Code:

```
                var itemsPerPage = 2; 
                 var courseStoreForGrid= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
              fields : [ 'id','name','minimumAge','maximumAge','suggestedDurationDays','tags'],
             storeId:'courseStoreForGrid',
             remoteSort:true,
             pageSize:itemsPerPage,
             sortInfo: 
             {
              field: "name",
              direction: "ASC"
            },
```

//autoLoad:true,
                     proxy :{
                type : 'rest',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/WebService/iTest/course/PagingCourse.json',
                method : 'GET',
                scope : this,
                reader : {
                            type : 'json',
                            root : 'course',
                            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                         }

```
        }

    });
                    courseStoreForGrid.load({params:{start:0, limit:2}});
```

I have total 7 records in my database . when I am performing paging  first  time  on that grid its working fine after its not working.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Ext-js are you using?

In below URLs, you can find official EXT-JS 4.x documentation with examples for both 'Grid panel' and 'Pagination toolbar plugin'

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

Comment: Hi , I am Using version 4.0.7